# QuickFixJ error: Message class

Tags: quickfixj

I'm new to FIX and QuickFixJ. Working on my application I got FIX reject with "Tag appears more than once:" for one of our incoming message. In order to debug the error I create a small Java app that uses the data dictionary provided by the client and the message that caused the issue. Here is the code for the debugging app (using quickfix/J version 1.6.3):

```
    import quickfix.DataDictionary;
    import quickfix.Message;

    ...

    DataDictionary d = new DataDictionary("clientDictionary.xml");
    String m = "FIX message taken from the application log. It has 102 tags";

    Message message = new Message(m,d,true);

    System.out.println("Message as text:" + message.toString());
    System.out.println("Message as xml:" + message.toXML(d));

    try{
      d.validate(message);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Validation Error:" + e.getMessage());
    }

...
```

When running the application, the first print (message.toString()) returns a FIX message with only 13 tags (the initial message in m has 102 tags). The same when printing the message in XML format (message.toXML(d)) I got only 13 tags. What is interesting is that the "CheckSum" field is changed from 102 (given in m) to 010 in the message object. Finally, when validating the message (d.validate(message)) it throws the following error: "Tag specified out of required order, field=1128". This, instead of helping me with debugging the initial problem, raises a few questions:

1. How come the object created from the input FIX messages contains only 13 tags and not 102?
2. How come the dictionary validation throws an error that is not raised when creating the dictionary (new Message(m,d,true)  - true means with validation)?

Not sure if it helps but here are the fields returned by message.toXML(d) method (only 1 field in the body):

```
header
field name="BeginString" tag="8"
field name="BodyLength" tag="9"
field name="MsgSeqNum" tag="34"
field name="MsgType" tag="35"
field name="SenderCompID" tag="49"
field name="SendingTime" tag="52"
field name="TargetCompID" tag="56"
field name="OnBehalfOfCompID" tag="115"
field name="DeliverToCompID" tag="128"
field name="MessageEndcoding" tag="347"
field name="ApplVerID" tag="1128"

body
field name="ApplExtID" tag="1156"

trailer
field name="CheckSum" tag="10"
```

There are many fields in the original FIX message m that are missing. For example field name="Price" tag="44". For me it seems that it is using a different dictionary. I also tried with other standard dictionaries like FIX50SP2.xml  but the result was exactly the same.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: "Tag appears more than once" and missing fields usually implies a config or DD issue.  Do you have **DataDictionary=path/to/clientDD.xml** *and* **UseDataDictionary=Y** in your config?

Comment: Yes, the config file contained the path to the dictionary. Actually because  it failed with the dictionary I tried to create this small app to investigate what is the issue. This java app does not use any config file it manually load the dictionary.

Comment: No matter how your config gets loaded (and I highly recommend using a file), you need to have those two settings.  You /can/ /not/ parse messages with repeating groups unless your engine has a DD and has been instructed to use it.  (Without a DD, your engine *can't* know where each group starts and ends.)

Comment: Thanks Grant, not sure I understand, In my example I load the dictionary ( DataDictionary d = new DataDictionary("clientDictionary.xml"); ) so the dictionary is loaded, the problem is that when creating the message based on the FIX string and dictionary it does not fail but it produces a useless message that contains less tags than the original message.

Comment: I've never parsed messages in QF/j the way you are doing, so I don't know exactly how that Message constructor works.  My advice with the config file was more relevant to a full QF app rather than your test snippet.  I'm afraid I don't have a Java environment up right now, so I don't know if I can help much more.

Comment: Thanks Grant. I tried with the config file with dictionary but it didn't work and with my small code I tried to debug why with the dictionary in the config file raised the "Tag appear more than once" error.